# Sum elements along a line of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a big matrix of shape (977,699). I would like to compute the sum of the elements along a line that starts approximately from the center of the matrix. The angle of the line should vary from 0 to 180 degrees (with respect to another line that passes from the center of the matrix) with steps of 20 degrees. For each step I want to have the sum of the elements, thus the output should be a numpy array of 10 elements. How could I do that in numpy?

I think I have found the way of doing what I want but I still need help. Here there is an example:

```
data = array([[  0.,   3.,   0.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   3.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  18.,  15.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.,  23.,  19.,  20.,  20.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,  20.,  22.,  26.,  23.,  18.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.,  23.,  16.,  20.,  13.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  18.,  20.,  18.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
              [  0.,   4.,   0.,   0.,   3.,   0.,   0.,   3.,   0.,   0.]])

def index_coords(data, origin=None):
    """Creates x & y coords for the indicies in a numpy array "data".
    "origin" defaults to the center of the image. Specify origin=(0,0)
    to set the origin to the lower left corner of the image."""
    ny, nx = data.shape
    if origin is None:
       origin_x, origin_y = nx // 2, ny // 2
    else:
        origin_x, origin_y = origin
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny))
    x -= origin_x
    y -= origin_y
    return x, y

def cart2polar(x, y):
    """Transform carthesian to polar coordinates"""
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return r, theta

a,b = index_coords(data,origin=(4,4)) 
r,theta = cart2polar(b,a)

degree = theta*(180.0/np.pi) # degrees 
d = degree.astype(np.int) # from float to integer (degrees at all pixels)

d = array([[-135, -143, -153, -165,  180,  165,  153,  143,  135,  128],
           [-126, -135, -146, -161,  180,  161,  146,  135,  126,  120],
           [-116, -123, -135, -153,  180,  153,  135,  123,  116,  111],
           [-104, -108, -116, -135,  180,  135,  116,  108,  104,  101],
           [ -90,  -90,  -90,  -90,    0,   90,   90,   90,   90,   90],
           [ -75,  -71,  -63,  -45,    0,   45,   63,   71,   75,   78],
           [ -63,  -56,  -45,  -26,    0,   26,   45,   56,   63,   68],
           [ -53,  -45,  -33,  -18,    0,   18,   33,   45,   53,   59],
           [ -45,  -36,  -26,  -14,    0,   14,   26,   36,   45,   51]])
```

Once I have "d array", I want to sum all the elements of "data array" which are located at the same degrees with respect to the origin, i.e. along 180, along 165, along 161 and so on till zero degrees. The output should be an array containing degree and the sum of element for that degree, i.e. out = array ([[180,sum along 180],[165, sum along 165],...[0, sum along 0]]). Could you help me with that? Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want: what is a "line" in a matrix, especially one that varies? It appears you want to apply geometry to the notion of a matrix. Perhaps a little sketch can help. Also: what have you so far tried yourself?

Comment: Have a look at the example I've just edited, I hope it is more clear..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the radon transform contains the projection you are looking for or possibly is what you are describing. An example with code for the transform along with some reconstruction methods can be found in the scikit-image documentation [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_radon_transform.html)

Try copying and pasting this:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import radon

image = np.zeros([100, 100])
image[25:75, 25:50] = np.arange(25)[np.newaxis, :]

angles = np.linspace(0., 180., 10)

# If the important part of the image is confined 
# to a circle in the middle use circle=True
transformed = radon(image, theta=angles)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(image)
plt.matshow(transformed.T)
plt.show()
```

The `transformed` matrix contains one column per angle and all projection lines in the direction encoded this angle over the whole image. If your image is circular, it is useful to specify `circle=True` so that it does not project the borders.

Comment: Unfortunately I am having trouble to install the skimage package and I cannot try out your example. I edit the new code, can you please look at that? Thanks

Comment: OK, could you just take a quick look at the wikipedia entry for radon transform to see if this is actually what you want?

Comment: OK, from what you describe, your problem is a sort of subproblem of the radon transform. What is necessary, if you want to do this by hand, is to smooth the lines slightly, otherwise you will probably miss many relevant pixels.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: you need to build a set of matrices that represent the rays along which you want to look. Since the radon transform does something like this, you can go and take the relevant part of their code without installing skimage (but it would be better to just install it). You would need to apply the transformation 4x separately on each quarter of the image