# Summing array entries along a particular line, python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array, and would like to sum its entries along a particular line. It should basically be like `numpy.sum()`, not along a column or row but rather along a line (given by an equation).

I don't really know where to start from. There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328473/sum-elements-along-a-line-of-numpy-array) which uses a Radon transfer (though I haven't managed to porperly install the skimage package).

Is there any built-in function I can start from?

Comment: Are you talking about a list of lists? That is, defined `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`?

Comment: First you have to identify the points on that line.  Once you have those the sum is trivial.  Elaborate on how you'd identify those points.  Use iterative code and and example if possible.  We may be able to suggest improvements.

Comment: @bendl Yes it is a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

def points_on_line(x0,y0, x1,y1):
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    D = 2*dy - dx
    y = y0

    for x in range(x0, x1):
        yield (x,y)
        if D > 0:
            y = y + 1
            D = D - 2*dx
        D = D + 2*dy


print(sum([array[y][x] for x, y in points_on_line(0,0, 5, 4)]))
```

This uses [Bresenheim's Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to find the points lying on the line between two points. It's not perfect though, and won't return **all** the points that it touches. This should be a good jumping off point, though!